# Trouble with Nvidia GPU and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 16.04, nvidia, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 710 with a Nvidia Geforce 940M graphics card. I've looked at all the instructions online including adding `nomodeset` or `nouveau.modeset=0` to the linux line after hitting `e` on the grub menu during boot. I've also tried disabling secure boot.

None of these seem to work, as I'm able to get into the login after doing `nouveau.modeset=0` after purging all nvidia drivers from the recovery boot shell. But whenever I install the nvidia drivers and try to reboot, it always freezes, and then I'm back to square one. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To boot I had to edit the linux line on grub with `acpi = off nouveau.modeset=0` Then I had to update the kernel to generic 4.7. Things seem to work now.

Comment: Instead of installing an unsupported kernel it is better to install Nvidia drivers, then remove the boot options.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I had to install nvidia drivers and then update the kernel.  Just doing the drivers wasn't enough in my case, probably because my machine is newer and the default kernel on install was the 4.4 kernel.