# Blank Screen on startup (18.04, Nvidia 1080ti)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying not to make this a duplicate, but I've followed the advice of helpful commenters in similar threads and haven't gotten anywhere:

I’ve recently set up my first Linux machine, and it’s been working for the past day as I configure Cuda/CuDNN/Tensorflow-gpu and all that.

i5 8600k, Z370-E, Nvidia 1080ti
Single booted (I believe this is the term?) Ubuntu 18.04

Now on boot-up I get the bios prompt, a brief purple/black screen, and then a black screen.

I’ve read “This usually happens because you have an Nvidia or AMD graphics card, or a laptop with Optimusor switchable/hybrid graphics, and Ubuntu does not have the proprietary drivers installed to allow it to work with these.”

I’ve heard that the solution is to boot Ubuntu once in nomodeset mode (or possible noveau.modeset=0, or nvidia.modeset=0) to bypass the black screen, then download and install the proper drivers, and then reboot to fix.

I’ve entered the Grub2 menu on boot using Esc and inserted either nomodeset or noveau.modeset=0 or nvidia.modeset=0 either before “quiet splash”, replacing “quiet splash”, or simply at the end of the linux line.

(I’ve ever tried adding nvidia-drm.modeset=1 to the linux line in grub2 and booting. No dice.
Have tried adding acpi=off along with the others. Didn’t change anything.
Adding grub_gfxmode=1280x1024x24 didn't help either  )

None of these have worked; that is, upon pressing F10/Ctrl+X, the text “Ubuntu” has flashed for a moment, and then the screen has went black.

I understand that when I’m able to boot successfully, I’ll have to enter TTY with Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2, F3, …), then purge and then reinstall some new nvidia drivers. If someone could help out with up-to-date cli arguments for that as well, I’d be thankful.

Comment: Note: Here are some of the threads I've used to try to solve my problems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/822333/trouble-with-nvidia-gpu-and-ubuntu-16-04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/697389/blank-screen-ubuntu-15-04-update-with-nvidia-driver-nomodeset-does-not-work +more

Comment: Could you please post output of the commands: `ubuntu-drivers devices` and `lspci -knn | grep VGA -A3`

Comment: So I don't think that I can input those commands anywhere? I can't get to TTY or past the login screen to use the terminal. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Would a possible strategy to flash a thumb drive with an earlier copy of linux (16.04), boot from that, clear my SSD, and restart the whole process?